# TCP error [RST, ACK] in the session between my libcurl client and a http server

Tags: c++, c, curl, tcp, libcurl

I m using libcurl as a http client in my application. my application establixh tcp session with libcurl to a http server and exchange with it some http message.

when I launch a capture, I remak sometimes a tcp error packet in the tcp packets

what is the cause of this problem? and how I can avoid it?

[image: TCP error in the session between libcurl client and a http server]

Comment: [RST, ACK] is symptomatic response to [SYN] when the port is closed. So I cannot see upper lines there, but I would expect to see port 10301 (80.202.14.115) > port 37555 (80.202.249.213) [SYN]. Is this the case?

Comment: Refining this idea, maybe you try to open another tcp connection to port 37555 while there is no listener, and then you try port 37556 which respond with [SYN], [ACK] in the picture?